# Same attributes, different tables in one database in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, attributes

I am just new in SQLite and I have this assignment in creating database schema using the said program.

I just want to ask if it is allowed to give a same attributes present in different tables inside a single database. Let me give the SQLite statements of two tables in one database.

```
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

/* Create a table called Employee */
CREATE TABLE Employee(Name text, Phone_number varchar);

    /* Create a table called Company */
CREATE TABLE Company(Name text, Country text);
```

I am referring to attribute Name which appears twice in two tables. Will it affect or distorts some of the SQL queries execution in the database?

Answer (score 0):

If you had tried it (in the [command-line shell](http://www.sqlite.org/cli.html) or on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5)), you would have found out that it is allowed.

However, it can affect your queries.
When you join these two tables, you have to explicitly specifiy which table's column you want:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee(ID, CompanyID, Name, Phone_number);
CREATE TABLE Company(ID, Name, Country);

SELECT Company.Name,
       Employee.Name,
       Phone_number
FROM Company
JOIN Employee ON Company.ID = Employee.CompanyID;
```

On the other hand, if you have a foreign key relationship, using the same name in both tables allows you to simplify the join condition:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee(EmployeeID, CompanyID, Name, Phone_number);
CREATE TABLE Company(CompanyID, Name, Country);

SELECT Company.Name,
       Employee.Name,
       Phone_number
FROM Company
JOIN Employee USING (CompanyID);
```

Comment: @CLOn your first example

Comment: On your first example, are you saying that when i can explicitly specify the table's column in my query, there would be no problem in using 2 same attributes in 2 different tables? On your second example, you have mentioned about declaring foreign key relationship. That is one thing i don't know how to make statement with foreign key relationship using my given example. I would be grateful if you can teach me to code it if it is a greater way that 2 same attributes in different tables be allowed.